# Is it possible to use indices as xtic values in a histogram?

Tags: indexing, gnuplot, histogram

In a file with the data in the following structure:

```
# [year]
"Town A" population
"Town B" population
"Town C" population

# [year2]
"Town A" population
"Town B" population
"Town C" population

# [year3]
"Town A" population
"Town B" population
"Town C" population
```

I have managed to create a histogram using the following:

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram columnstacked
p 'file.dat' index '[year]' u 2:key(1) ,\
'' index '[year2]' u 2,\
'' index '[year3]' u 2;
```

The previous settings produce the graph almost the way I need it, however, I would like to be able to use the index names (tags?) as xtic values, as of this moment, the xtic values are 0, 1, and 2 instead of year, year2 and year3.
Can gnuplot use index values as xtics in a histogram with such data structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see a way to set this up inside the `plot` command itself.  It's a great idea and I'll push it on as a feature request for gnuplot.  The best I can suggest is this, which assumes you know the set of index strings in advance.
I show it as an iteration over N because I assume you may really have more than 3 and for larger numbers the iteration is far less typing.

```
N = 3
array INDEX[N] = [ "[year1]", "[year2]", "[year3]" ]
set xtics 1
set for [i=1:N] xtics add (INDEX[i] i-1)

plot 'file.dat' index INDEX[1] u 2:key(1) ,\
     for [i=2:N] '' index INDEX[i] u 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The feature has been added in the latest release (gnuplot 5.2.5) but that won't help you with older versions.

Comment: I compiled version 5.2.5, how would I go about using the new feature, xtic(something) key(something)?

Answer (score 1):

Two blanks lines needed between data blocks in file.dat:

```
# [year]
"Town A" 123
"Town B" 543
"Town C" 789


# [year2]
"Town A" 234
"Town B" 666
"Town C" 1000


# [year3]
"Town A" 345
"Town B" 600
"Town C" 800
```

Gnuplot commands (requires version 5.2.5 or newer)

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram columnstacked
set style fill solid border lc black
plot 'file.dat' index '[year]' u 2:key(1) title strcol(-2),\
     '' index '[year2]' u 2 title strcol(-2),\
     '' index '[year3]' u 2 title strcol(-2)
```

Note that column -2 refers to the index value.  That much is not new, but version 5.2.5 now allows you to use it in the strcol() function (short name for stringcolumn()). The title and column spacing could be improved.
[image]

Comment: It works on SVG terminal but not when using pngcairo:

Comment: It works in QT terminal but not when I set the terminal to pngcairo: `set term pngcairo enhanced color transparent background '#FFFFFF'` results in [this] (https://i.postimg.cc/pTm9C279/poblacion.png) while using QT terminal in [this] (https://i.postimg.cc/SxZNvBcc/qttermpopulation.png)

Comment: That makes zero sense to me.  None of the code involved depends on the terminal output layer.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it. Also, the recommendation in the manual regarding the naming of the indices, as you can see makes xlabels look well, ugly, Is it imperative to have the naming of indices [string] or ==string==?

Comment: Not that I know of.  That advice is just somebody's suggestion based I suppose on their own experience and usage pattern.

Comment: I don't know what is going on with my system, but the problem with my labels in pngcairo either resolved itself or i was making some mistake. Thanks for all the help.